# Recovery deleted log files at logback worked fine on Windows but didn't work on Linux SUSE

Tags: java, linux, windows, slf4j, logback

I using `SLF4J` + `logback 1.0.12` for my application logging infrastruction. I run my application on both `Windows XP` and `Linux SUSE` os.
I have a scenario as following:

I deleted log files when my application is running. On `Windows XP` logback recovery mechanism worked fine and after passing some seconds (about 10 seconds) log files generate again but on `Linux SUSE` log files don't generate again.

My question is : Why logback recovery mechanism has different behavior on two os?

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, if a process writes to a file and the target file is removed, the process continues to *quietly* write to a ghost file. The error condition does not trigger an exception.

This answers why the recovery process behavior depends on the OS.

Comment: No, I haven't. What do it? What is it solution?