# Logback does not recreate deleted logfiles on Linux

Tags: logback

I'm using Logback's RollingFileAppender on a Linux server. If I delete the logfile while the process is running Logback (1.0.13) does not seem to recreate it and log messages are lost.

I found another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371985/recovery-deleted-log-files-at-logback-worked-fine-on-windows-but-didnt-work-on), where the answer is that the recovery mechanism is OS specific.

Has anyone found a way to have Logback recreate the file or call a StatusListener if it detects that the file has been deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using a custom FileAppender that extends RollingFileAppender and overrides writeOut(). Use openFile(getFile()) to recreate the file after checking that it does not exist.

Comment: I wonder if this is not very efficient. Do you check file existence on every log event?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to this code any more, but I think yes. Not necessarily a problem unless you have strict performance requirements.